# How to know which version of cocoapods suits my xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Sorry to bother with basic question.
would like to know which version of any cocoapods, suits particular xcode version. If  I know the exact podfile version for my xcode directly can be used without any interruption

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to save everybody and yourself a lot of trouble and use a fairly recent verion of both xcode and cocoapods.

Comment: Yes your right, but in my project which is running in xcode8.2.1 need to implement some functionalities through pods. which is giving me a headache to find out correct version for my xcode. These pod files are giving error at archiving project. Any how thank you